# How does Laravel handle PUT requests from browsers?

Tags: laravel

I know browsers only support `POST` and `GET` requests, and Laravel supports `PUT` requests using the following code:

```
<?= Form::open('/path/', 'PUT'); ?>
    ... form stuff ...
<?= Form::close(); ?>
```

This produces the following HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/home/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    ... form stuff ...
</form>
```

How does the framework handle this?  Does it capture the `POST` request ***before*** deciding which route to send the request off to?  Does it use ajax to send an actual `PUT` to the framework?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It inserts a hidden field, and that field mentions it is a PUT or DELETE request

[See here](http://laravel.com/docs/views/forms):

```
echo Form::open('user/profile', 'PUT');
```

results in:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Then it looks for _method when routing in the `request.php` core file (look for 'spoofing' in the code) - and if it detects it - will use that value to route to the correct restful controller.

It is still using "POST" to achieve this. There is no ajax used.

Comment: Request class is from Symfony's HttpFoundation wrapper for HTTP protocol.

[See Symfony's API for Request Class](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)

Comment: @NBPalomino 's response here should be the accepted answer because it actually answers the underlying question. Understanding Symfony is really important in getting (no pun intended) how Laravel routing actually works.

Comment: @mike The question specifically says "how does the Laravel framework handle it". Yes, it uses Symfony components - but at the end of the day the implementation is through Laravel. The question is posed through the use of the Laravel Form::open() - which is a specific Laravel implementation.

Comment: HTTP and HTML specs really need to start including PUT and DELETE, even TRACE and OPTIONS.

Answer (score 14):

Laravel uses the symfony Http Foundation which checks for this _method variable and changes the request to either PUT or DELETE based on its contents. Yes, this happens before routing takes place.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an array within your form open like so:

```
{{ Form::open( array('route' => array('equipment.update', $item->id ),
'role' => 'form',
'method' => 'put')) }}
```

Simply change the method to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

While a late answer, I feel it is important to add this for anyone else who finds this and can't get their API to work.

When using Laravel's resource routes like this:

```
Route::resource('myRoute','MyController');
```

It will expect a `PUT` in order to call the `update()` method. For this to work normally (outside of a form submission), you need to make sure you pass the *ContentType* as **x-www-form-urlencoded**. This is [default for forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html), but making requests with cURL or using a tool like [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) will not work unless you set this.

Answer (score 1):

PUT usually refers to update request.

When you open a form inside laravel blade template using,

```
{{ Form::open('/path/', 'PUT') }}
```

It would create a hidden field inside the form as follows,

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
```

In order for you to process the PUT request inside your controller, you would need to create a method with a put prefix,

```
for example, putMethodName()
```

so if you specify,

```
{{ Form::open('controller/methodName/', 'PUT') }}
```

inside Form:open. Then you would need to create a controller method as follows,

```
class Controller extends BaseController {
    public function putMethodName()
    {
        // put - usual update code logic goes here
    }
}
```