# What is the value of using PUT/DELETE with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4

For defining a route as a resource with `Route::resource`, the docs indicate:

```
Verb        Path                            Action  Route Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------
GET         /resource                       index   resource.index
GET         /resource/create                create  resource.create
POST        /resource                       store   resource.store
GET         /resource/{resource}            show    resource.show
GET         /resource/{resource}/edit       edit    resource.edit
PUT/PATCH   /resource/{resource}            update  resource.update
DELETE      /resource/{resource}            destroy resource.destroy
```

as per typical REST CRUD so PUT/PATCH is used for update actions and DELETE for destroy actions. I would think that is meant to define a typical resource interaction, even when manually defining my own routes and controller actions.

Here's the core of what I understand about these interactions with Laravel:

- You can define a route to accept PUT with `Route::put` and DELETE with `Route::delete.`
- The `Input` facade uses `Illuminate\Http\Request::input` typifying interactions and will return `json_decode` of content for json,  all GET parameters for GET requests or all POST parameters otherwise. We must use json or not actually use PUT or DELETE at all (fine because http PUT and DELETE requests are not universally supported).
- [Laravel's own form helpers use POST for PUT and DELETE requests, including a `_method` in the data so that the routing can enforce the verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757041/3109014).

Are PUT and DELETE solely there to create externally-accessible json REST APIs or do they serve another purpose? Is there some benefit aside from routing to the same URI with a different endpoint, enforcing the presence of a `_method` in `$_POST` or the json?

PUT and DELETE are supposed to be idempotent, but is this even implemented in Laravel? Is this something that I have to make happen in my controllers or does the routing enforce this somehow?

**Essentially, if PUT and DELETE in Laravel are functionally identical to POST, aside from REST semantics and parallel routing, when and why should I use them over POST?**

Comment: Answer is contained in your question - you should use PUT and DELETE when dealing with RESTful actions, if you require those verbs. As with everything - you don't really have to do it.

Comment: I tried to make the question clear by including a complete description of the scenario, but you're right that it was leading. Your answer is that yes, they are there solely for external REST APIs and that they hold no benefit aside from conforming to the standard verbs of the REST interaction model? No idempotence or other meaning? Internally, I could use POST and distinct URIs to the same function. How disappointing. Any source on the lack for idempotence? If you could make it an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Short answer: clarity.  If you're stepping in to a new project and looking through Routes to see what's happening and you see a `route::post`, all you really know is that something is getting posted to that route.  If you see `route::delete`, you know that at the end of that action, something should be deleted.  One of Laravel's overarching principles is to ensure code is expressive.

Comment: While HTML forms only support GET and POST, almost all AJAX implementations support PUT and DELETE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785248/which-browser-support-rest-completely-means-get-post-put-and-delete-method

Comment: @JamesBinford That's what I mean by "REST semantics" and "conforming to the standard verbs of the REST interaction model." It's all semantic. If routes have descriptive URIs and/or map to descriptive controller actions, then it should be clear as well. It is certainly expressive that it will enforce the presence of a `_method` with those verbs, but when it lacks the function behind the separation (in this case idempotency), it really becomes purely semantic akin to many html5 tags that simply resolve to <div>s in the end and only bloat the source.

Comment: @CollinJames Yes. That's what "enforcing the presence of a _method in ... the json" means - Laravel checks for the presence of _method. It should also be noted that Laravel's implementation does not check against xml as near as I can tell - just json, $_GET, and $_POST. That's all very semantic, but again, how is it functionally different?

Comment: @skovacs - Agreed - using REST semantics AND using descriptive URIs that map to clearly defined controller actions all come together to make maintenance and adding new members to the team much easier.

Comment: @skovacs1 thank you for wording this question in this way AND the use of "idempotence" - I learned two things.

What i found confusing is the encouragement of "modern" restful verbs; but the reality is the major players out there are using ancient apis. So all these methods do is add a layer of complexity at first. However, your onboarding reason was a good one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You use `PUT` method when you want to Update a record, And you use `DELETE` method when you want to Delete a record.

Note that in the resourceful controller, both `PUT` and `DELETE` method directed to the same `url (resource/{resource})`, so if you don't distinguish the method with `PUT` or `DELETE`, it will be a problem.

Comment: I think something's been missed. I used Route::Resource as an example before asking about defining my own routes. I wasn't asking for intended usage in REST. I ask specifically for the functional significance. Even in proper REST, they are significant in being idempotent, but Laravel misses that. Let's say I'm not using REST for some reason beyond the scope of the question - they're just pass-throughs for POST that the router contrives. I'm asking what good they are when they don't work as intended for proper REST. Regardless, this answer is too short - could you please improve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**GET:** To get data,

**POST:** To submit data,

**PUT:** To update data,

**DELETE:** To destroy data

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: When i need delete data, i can use this method: Post::whereId(1)->delete();  - So, what is the difference?)